# RedirectToAction causes "No route matches the supplied values" after adding a controller to the ASP.NET .NET6 Razor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a project, where I use the RedirectToAction Method to notify the app when some special data should be delivered to the website.
So I use the standard OnGet Method to decide which data must be loaded from the database

```
public void OnGet(int id, string action)
{
    if (action == "LOAD_AC") {
        //loaded after creation a new dataset .. do something special

    }
}

public IActionResult OnPostCreate()
{
    if (DataSelected != null && DataSelected.Id == 0)
    {            
       //create a new dataset in database 
       var res = CreateData(DataSelected, cn);
       if (res.Success)
       {
            //Return with the new ID to the OnGet Method to load the new dataset and display it   
            return RedirectToAction("LOAD_AC", new { id = newID });
        }
}
```

This works fine until I add a controller to my project. It could be a simple controller with only one Method and the method isn't called in the project for example:

```
namespace MyProject.Controller
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SendData : ControllerBase
    {

        public IActionResult SendDataToSomewhere()
        {
            return Ok();    
        }
    }
}
}
```

If the controller is added, the RedirectToAction Function fails with the Error:

> InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

The program.cs is left for basic to test the issue:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem or can explain why this is working and isn't after adding the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The RedirectToAction method is designed to generate a redirect to an action within a controller in an MVC application. You should use RedirectToPage when working with Razor Pages in your razor app.

Convert your **RedirectToAction** to **RedirectToPage** will work.

```
public IActionResult OnPostCreate()
{
    ...   
    // Here is the code
    return RedirectToPage("LOAD_AC", new { id = newID });
}
```

[image]